# OpenGL compute shader normal map generation poor performance

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, glsl, compute-shader

I have an height cube map and I want to generate a normal cube map texture from it. My height cube map is just a 2048x2048 image that I load at the beginning of the application for each face of the cube, and I can modify in real time a "maximum height" value which is used as a multiplicator when retrieving a pixel in the height map.

Initially I was calculating the normals in the vertex shader, but it gave me bad lighting results so I decided to move the calculations in the fragment shader.

As the height map does not change every frame (only when I modify the "maximum height" value), I want to generate a normal map texture from it, using a compute shader because I don't need any rasterization, but it gives me very poor performances.

With the fragment shader I ran at 200FPS but using the compute shader I run at 40 FPS.

Here is how I bind my images and start the compute work:

```
_computeShaderProgram.use();

glUniform1f(_computeShaderProgram.getUniformLocation("maxHeight"), maxHeight);

glBindImageTexture(
    0,
    static_cast<GLuint>(heightMap),
    0,
    GL_TRUE,
    0,
    GL_READ_ONLY,
    GL_RGBA32F
);

glBindImageTexture(
    1,
    static_cast<GLuint>(normalMap),
    0,
    GL_TRUE,
    0,
    GL_WRITE_ONLY,
    GL_RGBA32F
);

// Start compute work
// I only compute for one face of the cube map
glDispatchCompute(normalMap.getWidth() / 16, normalMap.getWidth() / 16, 1);

glMemoryBarrier(GL_SHADER_IMAGE_ACCESS_BARRIER_BIT);
```

And the compute shader:

```
#version 430 core
#extension GL_ARB_compute_shader : enable

layout(local_size_x = 16, local_size_y = 16, local_size_z = 1) in;

layout(rgba32f, binding = 0) readonly uniform imageCube heightMap;
layout(rgba32f, binding = 1) writeonly uniform imageCube normalMap;

uniform float maxHeight;

float getHeight(ivec3 heightMapCoord) {
    vec4 heightMapValue = imageLoad(heightMap, heightMapCoord);

    return heightMapValue.r * maxHeight;
}

void main() {
    ivec3 textCoord = ivec3(gl_GlobalInvocationID);

    // Calculate height of neighbors
    float leftCubePosHeight = getHeight(textCoord + ivec3(-1, 0, 0));
    float rightCubePosHeight = getHeight(textCoord + ivec3(1, 0, 0));
    float topCubePosHeight = getHeight(textCoord + ivec3(0, -1, 0));
    float bottomCubePosHeight = getHeight(textCoord + ivec3(0, 1, 0));

    // Calculate normal using central differences method
    vec3 horizontal = vec3(2.0, rightCubePosHeight - leftCubePosHeight, 0.0);
    vec3 vertical = vec3(0.0, bottomCubePosHeight - topCubePosHeight, 2.0);
    vec3 normal = normalize(cross(vertical, horizontal));

    imageStore(normalMap, textCoord, vec4(normal, 1.0));
}
```

I tried with different work groups sizes (width, width / 8, width / 16, width / 32) and local sizes (1, 8, 16, 32) but the performance is always poor, around 40 FPS or 20 FPS for work group with a size of the full width.

I know I can use shared memory for threads in the same work group to prevent fetching the same texture coordinate 4 times but later I will have height map generated procedurally and will be larger than 2048x2048 I think.

What is the difference between the fragment shader and the compute shader that make it so slow ? Am I doing something wrong ?

Is there any other solutions to generate this normal map ?

EDIT:

The fps I gave above are not right because I was generating 1/16 of the normal map (when I had 40FPS), and I also used the central differences technique to calculate the normals, which is cheap but does not give good lighting results, so I switched to Sobel technique, which is a little more expensive.

I made some tests to know which technique could give the best performance.
Each frame I generate the normal map (this will not be the case later, but it's just to test the performance). Here are my tests:

- CPU side single thread: 1.5FPS
- Compute shader with local sizes of 1 and one worker group for each image pixel: 4FPS
- Compute shader with local sizes of 16 and one worker group for each 16x16 image pixels block: 11FPS
- Fragment shader using framebuffer and MRT with 6 color attachments (one for each face of the normal map): 12.5FPS

This is a little laggy when I modify the max height (which generate the normal map again), but I think it's okay as I won't modify it a lot.

Comment: You say that you "don't need need rasterization", but you've just reimplemented rasterization in a compute shader.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more precise, I meant the interpolation of values between the vertex shader and the fragment shader.
I could use a vertex shader + fragment shader but I really don't need all the stages that happen in the graphics pipeline, and for that I also need to store a plane in a VBO.

Comment: That's okay, you don't have to use vertex interpolation. You also don't need to store a plane in a VBO, just create vertex data in the vertex shader from the vertex ID: https://rauwendaal.net/2014/06/14/rendering-a-screen-covering-triangle-in-opengl/ You say that you "don't need all the stages that happen in the graphics pipeline", but those stages are highly optimized with hardware implementations and you're not really paying extra to use them. The fragment shader will also be run in groups that optimize memory locality for texture accesses in common case, which your compute shader doesn't do

Comment: Basically, the normal graphics pipeline is heavily optimized to do exactly what you want to do, and using a compute shader throws away all the optimizations just so you can also get rid of some other parts. The expression "throwing the baby out with the bathwater" comes to mind.

Comment: Sorry for the late response.

Thank you @DietrichEpp for your help. You were right, the fragment shader is faster than the compute shader for my case (But close to the compute shader performances, see my EDIT).